# Sum of digits of $P(29)$, the sum of two recurrence series

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

$$G(x) = [G(x-1)+G(x-2)]^2\\
G(0) = 0,\quad  G(1) = 1$$

$$Q(x) = [Q(x-1)]^2 + [Q(x-2)]^2\\
Q(0) = 0,\quad Q(1) = 1$$

$$P(x) = G(x) + Q(x)$$
What is the sum of the digits of $P(29)$? I am unable to solve this problem. I got an answer, but I think it was wrong.

Comment: What was your answer?  How did you get it?

Comment: If you can solve one, you can solve the other: $Q(x) = \sqrt{G(x)}$.